# How to deal with truncation in inequations?

Tags: python, numpy, truncation, piecewise

I have an piecewise array generated by an x array

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 11) # = array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
y = np.piecewise(x,
                [x < p - h/2, (x >= p - h/2)&(x <= p + h/2), x > p + h/2],
                [     0     ,              10             ,      0     ])
```

With `p = 0.25` and `h = 0.1`. The mid interval `p - h/2 <= x <= p + h/2` can be re-written as `0.2 <= x <= 0.3`. That means that the 3rd and 4th elements of the `y` array should be `10`. But when applying this, the result was

```
array([ 0.,  0., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

I'm thinking that this is due to the python's truncation in the `p + h/2` operation. Is it right? If it is, how can I deal with it?

Comment: Looks to be a rounding error as you suggested. `from decimal import Decimal` and your numbers are: `Decimal(p+h/2) = Decimal('0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875')` and `Decimal(x[3]) = Decimal('0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125')` hence the error.

Comment: Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Out of interest it looks to be with numpy too: `0.3 <= p+h/2 >>> True` whilst `x[3] <= p+h/2 >>> False`. Also `np.float(0.3) <= p+h/2 >>> True` so it looks to be some rounding error with `linspace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem quickly I suggest adding a small float offset to the equality operators to make sure your values are included within the range:

```
import numpy as np
p = 0.25
h = 0.1
delta = 1e-10 # add small float offset to account for rounding error

x = np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)
y = np.piecewise(x,
                [x<p-h/2-delta, (x>=p-h/2-delta)*(x<=p+h/2+delta), x>p+h/2+delta],
                [     0       ,              10                  ,      0       ])

y
>>> array([ 0.,  0., 10., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

There are also functions `np.isclose` which are designed to deal with this, but I haven't managed to work out how to get them to deal with comparators yet, ie. `<=`. I'd be interested to know the solution to that.

Comment: This gives you the correct Boolean result for the middle condition: `np.logical_or(x>=p-h/2, np.isclose(x, p-h/2)) * np.logical_or(x<=p+h/2, np.isclose(x, p+h/2)) >>> array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])`, the only problem is that the final condition is still satisfied for `x[3]` so I think `piecewise` overwrites the result so overall `y` is still incorrect. Interesting problem.